# grep for string without another string before it

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have found lots of guides for ignoring lines with comments or matching for one string but not another, but I have not found what I need. I want to grep recursively for files containing the string "indexes" (case insensitive i think, it's apache conf) but not a "#" BEFORE it.

It should match this:

```
Options Indexes
Options +Indexes
Options Indexes MultiViews
Options Indexes # Comment
Options Indexes # Indexes
```

But not this:

```
Options MultiViews # Indexes
# Indexes yadayada Indexes
```

I'm using it in a script on the form:

```
if grep -re "[^#]*ndexes" $DIR1/httpd.conf $DIR2/http; then
    echo Do not use Indexes
fi
```

The above is one of my efforts, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: why it should match this `Options Indexes # Indexes` but not this `Options MultiViews # Indexes` ?

Comment: It is a comment but it is *also* a valid config line

Comment: `grep -E '^[^#]*Indexes'` should do the trick.

Comment: But it doesn't, and it's pretty much exactly what my not-working-example looks like.

Comment: Ah, it works after your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this input:

```
Options Indexes
Options +Indexes
Options Indexes MultiViews
Options Indexes # Comment
Options Indexes # Indexes
Options MultiViews # Indexes
# Indexes yadayada Indexes
```

This appears to work:

```
$ grep '^[^#]*Indexes' input
Options Indexes
Options +Indexes
Options Indexes MultiViews
Options Indexes # Comment
Options Indexes # Indexes
$ grep -v '^[^#]*Indexes' input
Options MultiViews # Indexes
# Indexes yadayada Indexes
```

To dissect the regular expression:

- `^` - Beginning of the line
- `[^#]*` - Zero or more of any character that is not an octothorpe
- `Indexes` - The literal string `Indexes`

To put it in the context of your script:

```
if grep -rl -- '^[^#]*Indexes' "$DIR1/httpd.conf" "$DIR2/http"; then
    echo "The above-listed files use an 'Indexes' directive."
fi
```

Comment: What is -- good for?

Comment: `--` signifies to many programs that there are no further arguments starting with `-` forthcoming, which is useful in the possible case that `$DIR1` or `$DIR2` happen to start with a hyphen.